# proof without axiom of choice

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I heard that I can't prove

'$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(a_n)=f(a)$ for all $\{a_n \}$ such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = a$ $\Longrightarrow$  $f$ is continuous at $a$'

without axiom of choice.

But I think I have proof not using axiom of choice. Of course I know my proof is wrong, but I can't find error. 
This is my proof.

1. RAA Hypothesis : Suppose $f$ is not continuous at $a$.
2. There is $\epsilon_0 >0$, for any natural number $n$, there is $x$ satisfying $|x-a|<\frac{1}{n}$ and $| f(x)-f(a)|> \epsilon_0$. Let's call $x$ $a_n$.
3. For all naturall number $n$, we know $(n, (n, a_n ))$ is set. Then $F = \{ (n, (n, a_n ))  \mid n \in \mathbb{N}  \}$ is class function, So $F( \mathbb{N} ) = \{ (n, a_n )  \mid n \in \mathbb{N}  \} $ is also set by axiom of replacement. (Or we can use axiom schema of separation for same purpose.)
4. now $ \{ (n, a_n )  \mid n \in \mathbb{N}  \} $ is a sequence, and now it is routine to derive contradiction.

You may tell me that I cannot take $x$ and give name $a_n$, but if so be, I think we cannot prove that there is choice function of finite set because its proof also contains part that give name to existing element.

Answer (score 1):

You're using AC in step 2. "Let's call it $a_n$"? There's no "it" here, there are many $a$ that work - you "choose" one to call $a_n$.

Oh - I just saw the last sentence "You may tell me that I cannot take $x$ and give name $a_n$, but if so be, I think we cannot prove that there is choice function of finite set because its proof also contains part that give name to existing element." The reason you need AC but a choice function for a finite set does not is that you're simultaneously "choosing" $a_n$ for infinitely many values of $n$. You're not just giving a name to *an* existing element.

Comment: Thank you for answer! But your answer cause me one more question.
Is there a axiom that allow choosing finitely many values of n? That is, is there axiom that guarantee existence of choice function of finite set? Or can it be proved by other ZFC axioms? Or is it a axiom of underlying first order logic?

Comment: The existence of a choice function for a finite set certainly does not require AC, it follows from the rest of ZF.

Comment: I think I (maybe) got the feel of the point. Thank you!